# adding event listener on one div and removing it when other div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs with text like this:

```
<div class="title">  <p>Editable title</p>  </div>
<div class="text">  <p>Editable text</p>  </div>
```

Now, I have a function called `checkClick(val)` which appends my own text editor to style text.

When an element with `class="title"` is clicked, the function should be called and only those `class="title"` paragraph(s) should be editable.

When an element with `class="text"` is clicked the function should be called and only those `class="text"` paragraph(s) should be editable.

I have tried this:

```
$(".title").click(function(){ checkClick(".title"); });
$(".text").click(function(){ checkClick(".text"); });
```

But now both divs have that event listener, and when I click bold in my editor both texts are bolded, but it should be that only the div that I selected before should be editable.

Comment: What does `checkClick()` do?

Comment: It shows my custom text editor and then it check which button on my editor was pressed and apply that command ex. bold to selected div.(title or text);

Comment: Please add your `checkClick()` function source

Comment: I guess that you should use 
`checkClick($(this));` instead of `checkClick(".text");` and `checkClick(".title");`

Comment: Link j08691 and oliakaoil said, this should be right - when the `.title` elements are clicked, then `checkClick(".title")` should be called, and same for the `.text` elements - there must be something wrong with your `checkClick()` function.

Comment: Since you said that *both* `div`s are being edited when you only want one to be edited, then does that mean you need to end the function before you call it again? Like when they click the other, then the last selected `div` would be unselected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about use jquery to set selected div as 'active' and then do whatever you like with the class?

```
function checkClick(target) {

  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(target).addClass('active');
  $('.active').doWhateverYouLike...
}
```